# How to assign a function inline to a value in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I like to assign the return value of a function to a variable, but inline. The following is how you would do it not inline.

```
bool isValid() {
    if(a == b) return true;
    if(a == c) return true;
    return false;
}

bool result = isValid();
```

What I want is something like

```
bool result = () {
    if(a == b) return true;
    if(a == c) return true;
    return false;
}
```

However it displays the error

> The argument type 'Null Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool'

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Out of interest why do you require this to be inline? Surely just creating a function to handle the logic would just be fine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are defining a lambda expression. This works the same way as in Javascript, Typescript or many other languages.

```
bool result = () {
    if(a == b) return true;
    if(a == c) return true;
    return false;
}
```

This code defines an anonymous function of type `() -> bool` (accepts no parameters and returns bool). And the actual type of the `result` variable is bool so the compilation is broken (`() -> bool` and `bool` are non-matching types).

To make it correct just call the function to get the result.

```
bool result = () {
    if(a == b) return true;
    if(a == c) return true;
    return false;
}();
```

Now you define an anonymous function (lambda) and then call it so the result is bool. Types are matching and there's no error.

This is rather an uncommon behaviour to define the function and immediately call it. It's used in Javascript to create a separate scope for variables using closures (some kind of private variables). I would recommend you to move the code to some kind of class or pass `a, b, c` parameters directly to the function:

```
bool isValid(a, b, c) {
    /* Your code */
}
```

It's more generic that way and could be reused. Immediately called lambda is often a sign of bad design.